# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Object> to BasketDTO

Tags: java, option-type

I have the following java 11 code but eclipse is showing error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Object> to BasketDTO`

```
    public BasketDTO findBasket(String key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(key).map(basketRepository::findOneByKey)
                .map(b -> b.map(BasketDTO::new).orElseGet(() -> new BasketDTO()));
    }

    Optional<BasketModel> findOneByKey(String key){
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `basketRepository::findOneByKey` returns an `Optional`, you can use `Optional#flatMap` instead of `Optional#map` so that you don't have to worry about nested `Optional`s:

```
public BasketDTO findBasket(String key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(key) // Optional<String>
            .flatMap(basketRepository::findOneByKey) // Optional<BasketModel>
            .map(BasketDTO::new)        // b -> new BasketDTO(b)
            .orElseGet(BasketDTO::new); // () -> new BasketDTO()
}
```